# Angular component's selector is blocking its content styling

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

So, I was building a wrapper component around Bootstrap's Input Group as follows:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'bootstrap-input',
    template: `
        <div class="{{ calculateColumns(cols) + ' input-group mb-3' }}">
            <div *ngIf="hasLabel" class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">{{ label }}</span>
            </div>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
    `,
})
export class BootstrapInput {
    @Input() cols: number[];
    @Input() label: string;
    @Input() hasLabel: boolean = true;

    /**
     * Given an array of columns in the following order:
     * [small, medium, large, x-large], this method will translate it
     * to the correct class.
     *
     * @example [12, 12, 4, 4] -> "col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"
     */
    calculateColumns(cols: number[]): string {
        let classString = `col-${cols[0]} col-sm-${cols[0]} col-md-${cols[1]} col-lg-${cols[2]} col-xl-${cols[3]}`;
        return classString;
    }
}
```

It will be used like this:

```
<div class="form-row">
  <bootstrap-input [cols]="[12, 12, 3, 3]" label="Name">
    <input class="form-control" />
  </bootstrap-input>

  <bootstrap-input [cols]="[12, 12, 3, 3]" label="Email">
    <input class="form-control" />
  </bootstrap-input>

  <bootstrap-input [cols]="[12, 12, 3, 3]" label="Phone">
    <input class="form-control" />
  </bootstrap-input>
</div>
```

***Next, scale your browser to be big, and it won't work.***

Now, for some reasons, the HTML, or to be more specific, the styling of the group is not working properly. If I opened the Debugging Console and removed the wrapping `bootstrap-input` tag, it works properly. It's worth mentioning that, this error only happens on > medium screen displays (large and extra-large).

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPCgR.png)

[Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9mhocz)

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apply the `display: flex` on your `.form-row` element, but the `col-*` classes  (with `flex:` css rules) on the element inside the wrapper. `flex:` rules should be applied on the children of the `display: flex`.

You should apply the column classes on your wrapper element directly, not its children, using `@HostBinding` is probably the easier solution.